# Convert Merge join into BIML - need NumKeyColumns changed to 1

Tags: join, merge, biml

I was almost ready with a BIML file but I have one more problem

I was trying to put the standard Merge Join into biml
and 99% works, and the component is generated and the dtsx is made but
I can not set the numKeyColumns value anywhere

```
 <properties>
            <property dataType="System.Int32" description="Specifies the type of join to perform." name="JoinType" typeConverter="JoinType">0</property>
            <property dataType="System.Int32" description="Specifies the number of columns in the ordering key." name="NumKeyColumns">0</property>
            <property dataType="System.Boolean" description="Indicates whether the null values are treated as equal values." name="TreatNullsAsEqual">true</property>
            <property dataType="System.Int32" description="Indicates the requested maximum buffers per input before blocking." name="MaxBuffersPerInput">5</property>
          </properties>
```

I could set the jointype
But I can not find the NumKeyColumns
when the dtsx is generated it will fill in 0
but is has to be 1

This is the merge join in biml (without the incoming connections)

```
            <MergeJoin Name="Merge Join" JoinType="FullOuterJoin">
          <LeftInputPath OutputPathName="Source.Output">
            <Columns>
              <Column SourceColumn="BK" IsUsed="true" SortKeyPosition="1" TargetColumn="sBK" />
              <Column SourceColumn="hbSource" IsUsed="true" />
            </Columns>
          </LeftInputPath>
          <RightInputPath OutputPathName="Dwh Destination.Output">
            <Columns>
              <Column SourceColumn="BK" IsUsed="true" TargetColumn="dBK" />
              <Column SourceColumn="hbDestination" IsUsed="true" />
            </Columns>
          </RightInputPath> 
        </MergeJoin>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you were missing the JoinKey attribute for the MergeJoin. Adding that allowed for the emission of a syntactically correct SSIS package. Whether it's logically correct is a different matter ;)

Let me know if that's not what you were trying to do. Happy to help, love Biml.

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Connections>
        <OleDbConnection Name="SRC" ConnectionString="Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=localhost\dev2016;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
    </Connections>
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="MergeJoin">
            <Tasks>
                <Dataflow Name="DFT Demo">
                    <Transformations>
                        <OleDbSource Name="Source" ConnectionName="SRC">
                            <Columns>
                                <Column SourceColumn="BK" SortKeyPosition="1" />
                            </Columns>
                            <DirectInput>SELECT 1 AS BK, 'foo' AS hbSource UNION SELECT 2, 'ick' order by 1;</DirectInput>
                        </OleDbSource>
                        <OleDbSource Name="Dwh Destination" ConnectionName="SRC">
                            <Columns>
                                <Column SourceColumn="BK" SortKeyPosition="1" />
                            </Columns>
                            <DirectInput>SELECT 1 AS BK, 'foo' AS hbDestination UNION SELECT 3, 'zoo' order by 1;</DirectInput>
                        </OleDbSource>
                        <MergeJoin Name="Merge Join" JoinType="FullOuterJoin">
                            <LeftInputPath OutputPathName="Source.Output">
                                <Columns>
                                    <Column SourceColumn="BK" IsUsed="true" SortKeyPosition="1" TargetColumn="sBK" />
                                    <Column SourceColumn="hbSource" IsUsed="true" />
                                </Columns>
                            </LeftInputPath>
                            <RightInputPath OutputPathName="Dwh Destination.Output">
                                <Columns>
                                    <Column SourceColumn="BK" IsUsed="true" TargetColumn="dBK" />
                                    <Column SourceColumn="hbDestination" IsUsed="true" />
                                </Columns>
                            </RightInputPath>
                            <JoinKeys>
                                <JoinKey LeftColumn="BK" RightColumn="BK" />
                            </JoinKeys>
                        </MergeJoin>
                    </Transformations>
                </Dataflow>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

Comment: You did it! 

yes I was missing that (I thought I added that, but maybe in another test version)

I tested 2 times to see if it really was working, and yes it did!

thanks, and I also love drinking tea :-)